# How to add a 'tabindex' for radio buttons in angular formly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angular-formly

I have a requirement to add a specific tabindex to radio button in my formly form.
I can do it for text field but not for radio buttons, below is the sample code, any help is appreciated -

Tried adding the tabindex=1 at three places, above templateOptions, inside templateOptions and inside options, none of them works to get the focus.

```
  {
    name: 'feedbackType',
    key: 'feedbackType',
    type: 'radio',
    id: 'feedbackType',
    //tabindex:'1',
    templateOptions: {
      label: Constant.feedbackForm.typeField,
      for:'feedbackType',
      required: true,
      focus: true,
      //tabindex:'1',
      options: [{
        name: 'Idea1',
        value: 'Idea1',
        //tabindex:'1'
      }, {
        name: 'Idea2',
        value: 'Idea2'
      }, {
        name: 'Idea3',
        value: 'Idea3'
      }]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Look into `ngModelElAttrs`

Comment: @kentcdodds modified as below but NO Luck, 

 {
        name: 'feedbackType',
        key: 'feedbackType',
        type: 'radio',
        id: 'feedbackType',
        ngModelElAttrs: {
          'tabindex': 'myTabindex'
        },
        templateOptions: {
          label: EaseConstant.feedbackForm.typeField,
          myTabindex:'1',
          options: [{
            name: 'Idea',
            value: 'Idea'
          }, {
            name: 'Problem',
            value: 'Problem'
          }, {
            name: 'Praise',
            value: 'Praise'
          }]
        }
      },

Comment: I think I got the issue, it's not overriding the default tabindex="0" provided by formly to radio buttons. @kentcdodds, any idea how to override any attribute e.g. tabindex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. You'll want to use `ngModelElAttrs`. Like [this](https://jsbin.com/ruveqa/edit?html,js,output)

```
  {
    name: 'feedbackType',
    key: 'feedbackType',
    type: 'radio',
    id: 'feedbackType',
    ngModelElAttrs: {
      tabindex: '1'
    },
    templateOptions: {
      label: EaseConstant.feedbackForm.typeField,
      for:'feedbackType',
      required: true,
      focus: true,
      options: [{
        name: 'Idea1',
        value: 'Idea1',
      }, {
        name: 'Idea2',
        value: 'Idea2'
      }, {
        name: 'Idea3',
        value: 'Idea3'
      }]
    }
  },
```

If you want it to be dynamic, then you can do:

```
ngModelElAttrs: {
  tabindex: '{{to.tabindex}}' // to is a shortcut for `options.templateOptions`
},
expressionProperties: {
  'templateOptions.tabindex': 'someFormlyExpression' // http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-expressions
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't see the output in your above jsbin link. angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/src/types/radio.html has the tabindex="0" which is not being overriden by the above solution. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: any hints, is it possible to remove the angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/src/types/radio.html has the tabindex="0" ? As I don't tabindex being added to any other html, e.g. https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/tree/master/src/types/…

Comment: @Ash, I can see jsbin link is working correctly for tabIndex using solution by kentcdodds. You should accept this answer, which will help other.